# Como percorrer e comparar dois arrays em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tenho dois arrays que voltam uma consulta do MySQL. Preciso comparar esses dois resultados para, a cada vez que forem diferentes, imprimir algo na tela. O problema é que a consulta que volta do banco é um array com vários campos, então tenho que percorrer os dois.

Estava tentando fazer assim:

```
include_once 'classes/trabalhosclass.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); } 

$idTrabalho = $_SESSION['SemestreGeral'];
$Busca = '';
$oTrabalho = new trabalhosclass();
$oTrabalho -> listarAvancado($Busca, $idSemestre);          

while ($arrayTrabalhos = mysql_fetch_array($oTrabalho->retorno())){
    $array1[] = $arrayTrabalhos['orientador'];
}

include_once 'classes/professoresclass.php';

$aux = '';
$oProfessor = new professoresclass();
$oProfessor -> listar($aux);          

while ($arrayProfessores = mysql_fetch_array($oProfessor->retorno())){
    $array2[] = $arrayProfessores['Nome'];
}

$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

Mas não funcionou... Será que teria uma outra forma? Precisava que ali no $result aparecesse todos os nomes que estão em uma e não na outra listas...

Comment: O `array_diff` retorna todos os nomes que estiverem na primeira mas não estiverem na segunda. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
$result = array_diff (
   array_unique( array_merge($array1, $array2) ),
   array_unique( array_intersect( $array1, $array2 ) )
);
print_r($result);
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/K5fLkl)**.